# Using the advanced query api and get all pages back

Tags: import.io

I can successfully call into an advanced query method and get the first page of data back (using the post option) refernced in http://api.docs.import.io/#QueryMethods

Anyone have an idea how to page after that?  I get 20 out of 190 results.  My query looks like:

```
    var query = {
    "input": { "last_name": name },
    "additionalInput": {
        "8d817939-my-api-key-9502ed72": cookie
    },
    "returnPaginationSuggestions": true
}
```

Where param name and cookie are known vars.

The results do not return a pagination block either as in the model result:

```
{
  "connectorVersionGuid": "string",
  "pagination": {
    "pattern": "string",
    "next": "string",
    "currentPageNum": 0,
    "previous": "string"
  },
  "connectorGuid": "string",
  "totalResults": 0,
  "errorType": "TimeoutException",
  "outputProperties": [
    {
      "type": "STRING",
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "cookies": [
    "string"
  ],
  "results": [
    {}
  ],
  "pageUrl": "string",
  "error": "string",
  "data": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response is not returning the "Pagination" block, it means that the system was not able to identify pagination on a given page.

As far as I remember pagination is flaky for Extractor APIs, while it works quite well for Magic APIs. I would recommend trying to get a Magic extractor, and getting pagination suggestions for it. Than you should be able to get the "Pagination" block in your response, and use "next" value to get the URL of the next page.

Comment: I would also suggest looking at the URL and see if it allows pagination within the actual URL parameters or if you need cookies to paginate.